# Plugin 'org.sonarlint.idea' failed to initialize and will be disabled. Please restart IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, sonarlint

I am getting the error above when I try to install the *SonarLint* plugin on my *IntelliJ*.

> Mac OS X Yosemite 10.10.5
>
> IntelliJ 15.06
>
> SonarLint Plugin 2.2 (tried 2.1 also)

My JDK is set to `1.8` but not sure what is causing the issue. Any help will be appreciated.

```
        Plugin 'org.sonarlint.idea' failed to initialize and will be disabled.  Please restart IntelliJ IDEA.

        com.intellij.diagnostic.PluginException: org/sonarlint/intellij/config/global/SonarLintGlobalSettings : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 [Plugin: org.sonarlint.idea]
        at com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader.b(PluginClassLoader.java:130)
        at com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader.a(PluginClassLoader.java:77)
        at com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:66)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:249)
        at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.a(ComponentManagerImpl.java:408)
        at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.init(ComponentManagerImpl.java:96)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:455)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:447)
        at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:194)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl$1$1$1.run(MainImpl.java:60)
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:715)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:82)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:676)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:674)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:86)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:685)
        at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:361)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:296)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:196)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:188)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
        Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/sonarlint/intellij/config/global/SonarLintGlobalSettings : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:637)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:471)
        at com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader._defineClass(UrlClassLoader.java:260)
        at com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader.defineClass(UrlClassLoader.java:256)
        at com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader._findClass(UrlClassLoader.java:225)
        at com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader.b(PluginClassLoader.java:124)
        ... 30 more
```

Comment: Could you post the stack trace?

Comment: I have added the Stacktrace.

Comment: any suggestion? my IntelliJ doesn't run if I have SonarLint enabled and get the error mentioned in the stack trace above; 
A user had a similar error where his/her phoStorm wasn't opening as a result of SonarLint and solution was to get a JDK higher than 1.7,which solved the issue. I believe I am already on 1.8, unless there are other places in IntelliJ where I should be setting this parameter.

Comment: I resolved this problem by giving permissions for the project folder - on Ubuntu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following indicates that the JDK you are running with is not able to load classes compiled with JDK 7: `Unsupported major.minor version 51.0`

Check the JDK used by Intellij in the menu 'IntelliJ => About IntelliJ Idea'.

SonarLint for IntelliJ 2.2 requires **JDK >= 7**. Also note that upcoming new versions will probably require **JDK >= 8**.

Comment: You're right, when I go on About IntelliJ Idea, it says 1.6
How do I change that to 1.8? I thought all my settings are to 1.8

Answer (score 3):

To change the JVM that intellij Uses by default refer https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23455956-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under.

You can Update /Applications/IntelliJ\ IDEA\ 14\ CE.app/Contents/Info.plist

and replace JVMVersion 1.6* with 1.8*

JVMVersion
1.8*